# Browsing bup backup with gitk or gitg

Tags: backup, git, bup

I am just playing around with `bup` for my backups and tested it like this:

```
BUP_DIR=/mnt/TestTarget/bup bup init
```

Which gave me the message: `Initialized empty Git repository in /mnt/TestTarget/bup/`

However in `/mnt/TestTarget` there seems to be not `.git` directory.

```
bup index -uv /home/user/TestSource
bup save -n buptest1 /home/user/TestSource
```

Now I want to browse the repository with `gitk`, I did `cd /mnt/TestTarget/bup` and `gitk` but it doesn't display anything. `gitg` gives me `Could not find git repository`.

So what's wrong here? How can I use `gitk` or `gitg` to browse my backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GHugo suggested, using the commands described in my question, produced a backup in `~/.bup`. There it is possible to browse it via `gitk` if you remember to click on tree (and not on patch).

Now If one wants a backup in `/mnt/TestTarget/bup` the following steps worked for me:

```
BUP_DIR=/mnt/TestTarget/bup bup init

bup -d /mnt/TestTarget/bup index -uv /home/user/TestSource
bup -d /mnt/TestTarget/bup save -n buptest1 /home/user/TestSource
```

Then the data and the index seems to be saved to `/mnt/TestTarget/bup` and you can `cd` to it ant execute `gitk` to browse it (clicking on tree to browse the initial commit). However there is no `.git` directory in it, so it seems to be a bare repository (correct my if I am wrong).

Answer (score 1):

You should have an `.git` directory into `/mnt/TestTarget/bup`.

Maybe your bup init goes wrong. In this case, look if you have the same directory (`.git`) inside `~/.bup`

Comment: There is no `.git` directory in `/mnt/TestTarget/bup` and no one in `~/.bup`. However if I do `gitk` in `~/.bup` I have some commits with the message `bup saved`. But there are no backed up files just `.bupm`'s which tells me how I invoked `bup save`...